# comparing to lists of data from two databases

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have a first list of tickets from the first database selected by user and i have a second list from another database 
I want to compare those two lists if the id of ticket is the same!
but i think there is something wrong in my code can any one help me please ?[the result is here in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCnDO.png)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            **strong text**
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\iharbahoui\Desktop\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\glpi.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from glpi_tickets where user_id_recipient =1", con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            adp.Fill(dt);

            if (dt.Rows.Count >0)
            {
                //créér une planification du ticket dans l'agenda de la ressource
                SqlConnection cnx = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\iharbahoui\Desktop\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\AZPbd.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
                cnx.Open();
                SqlCommand req1 = new SqlCommand("select * from planification where user_id =1",cnx);
                DataTable tb = new DataTable();
                SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(req1);
                adpt.Fill(tb);
                foreach (DataRow row1 in dt.Rows)
                {
                    foreach(DataRow row2 in tb.Rows )
                    {
                        if (row1["Id"].Equals(row2["idTicket"]))
                        {
                           Console.WriteLine("ticket existe deja");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine( "ticket n'existe");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine( "Ticket n'existe pas");
            }
            con.Close();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what exactly do you think is wrong? It doesn't seem to be crashing. Don't forget we can't see your source data. Are you saying it doesn't produce the expected results? If so you need to provide the results you expect and a sample of the data before anyone can realistically spot a problem.

Comment: debug your code step by step - is normal to have this message on this kind of loop.

Answer (score 0):

*Brief: Use left outer join instead of full outer join.*

---

The main problem is that in the inner `foreach` loop you output comparison result of `glpi_tickets.id` with *every* `planification.idTicket` thus resulting into full cartesian product of 9 lines total.

What you really want is just left outer join (check all `planification.idTicket` items but output only once per `glpi_tickets.id`). With minimal changes to your code this can be achieved by this modification:

```
foreach (DataRow row1 in dt.Rows)
{
    bool matchFound = false;
    foreach (DataRow row2 in tb.Rows)
        if (row1["Id"].Equals(row2["idTicket"]))
        {
            matchFound = true;
            break;
        }
    Console.WriteLine(matchFound ? "ticket existe deja" : "ticket n'existe");
}
```

---

Alternatively, you may perform the outer join in a single query on the server side. Leave only one (first) connection and within it refer to the second database/table using full name:

```
select ...
from glpi_tickets t 
left outer join AZPbd.dbo.planification p
...
```

And the whole program would look like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\iharbahoui\Desktop\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\glpi.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        var query = @"
            select t.id, 
                case 
                    when (p.idTicket is null) then 'ticket n''existe' 
                    else 'ticket existe deja' 
                end as ticket_exists
            from glpi_tickets t 
            left outer join AZPbd.dbo.planification p 
                on t.id = p.idTicket
                and p.user_id = @userId
            where t.user_id_recipient = @userId";
        var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userId", 1);
        var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        var ticketsFound = false;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", reader["id"], reader["ticket_exists"]);
            ticketsFound = true;
        }
        if (!ticketsFound)
            Console.WriteLine("Ticket n'existe pas");
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: thinks for the help :) i found another solution more easier